# Variant variable type receives runtime error 13

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a small script in VBA that does a basic drilldown and collects data from the files it finds and puts them into arrays. I know I am finding the right files and I am making sure to redim my arrays to accommodate new additions (and yes I open the files before trying to access data). Regardless I'm getting a data type mismatch (runtime error 13) when I try to access cell values in the sheets. This occurs on the first file accessed which I know is a xls file.

```
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    
        length = UBound(Inspections)

        ReDim Preserve Inspections(length + 1)
        ReDim Preserve fridgeDoc(length + 1)
        ReDim Preserve fridgeWalk(length + 1)
        ReDim Preserve nrgEff(length + 1)
        ReDim Preserve mheDoc(length + 1)
        ReDim Preserve mheWalk(length + 1)
        ReDim Preserve buildingDoc(length + 1)
        ReDim Preserve buildingWalk(length + 1)
        
        Workbooks.Open oFile
        
        'error occurs at line directly below
        burner = Workbooks(oFile).Worksheets(1).Cells(11, 3)
        
        MsgBox (VarType(burner))
```

This is even more puzzling because for diagnostic purposes I made a burner variable of Variant type and I don't know what could even violate a variant data type. If I could get any tips on further debugging techniques that'd be awesome. Localized code snippet included. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is likely `Workbooks(oFile)`. You really should be using a `Workbook` variable to which you assign the result of `Workbooks.Open`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

`burner = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(11, 3).Value`

Workbooks open in excel are referenced by their name, not by their full path.

Ideally though, as noted by BigBen, it's tidier to do something like:

```
With Workbooks.Open(oFile)
    burner = .Worksheets(1).Cells(11, 3).Value
    .Close False
End with
```